# python mysql linked columns

Tags: python, mysql

I have a DB structure like this.

```
                            |songs| (DB)

            |artist|  |albums|    |songs|      |album review|
             artid     albid       songid       reviewid
             artname   albname     songnames    reviewauthor 
                            .            .      reviews
                            .            .
                            .            .
```

I have added  `constraint` in tables like so.

```
artid < albid(in albums)
songid > albid(in songs)
reviewid > albid(in album review)
```

All this data is being added while being scraped. I get this error when I try to add a single value at a time:

```py
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO albums VALUES ('albname', %s)", (alb,))
```

Error:

```
python-mysql-column-count-doesnt-match-value-count-at-row-1
```

when I remove the comma after `alb`.

I get

```
MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: not all arguments converted during bytes formatting
```

I am just starting out with MySQL so, I am not sure is this because of the scraping part or the keys have not been set up properly. Any pointers to some reading material would also immensely help.

```
import MySQLdb
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
            
db = MySQLdb.connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'songs')
cursor = db.cursor()
db.autocommit(True)
#Load FireFox Profile
profile = FirefoxProfile(r'C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\ogwfse3l.default-release')

url = input("Enter the artist url :") #Get Url
binary = FirefoxBinary("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe") #Set Binary
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, executable_path="C:\\geckodriver.exe", firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get(url)

profile_name = False

while True:
    try:

        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        time.sleep(5)

        divs = main_div.find_elements_by_xpath('xpath')
        if len(divs) > 5:
            for i in range(i+1,len(divs)):

                driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", divs[i])
                action = ActionChains(driver)
                action.move_to_element(divs[i]).perform()
                time.sleep(13)
                a_name = divs[i].find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="class"]//span').text  # poster's name
                al_name = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//div[@class="class"]//a')[i]
                a_link = pi_link.get_attribute('href')
                post_content = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="class"]')[i]
                so_link = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="class"]//a')[i]
                post_link = so_link.get_attribute('href')
                if not profile_name:
                    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO artname VALUES ('name', %s)", (a_name,))
                profile_name = True
                breakpoint()
                cursor.execute("INSERT INTO posts VALUES ('albname', %s)", (alb))
```

The elements are all being scraped successfully.

Comment: Could you please have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and post enough of your to reproduce the error? For example, it is not clear which libraries you are using.